# AWS elastic load balancing

Tags: amazon-web-services

I am fairly new to AWS.While learning the AWS course,I get this question.

Will AWS loadbalancer scale up and down? How it happens?

Because ,I understand  ec2 would scale up and down based on the scaling policy configuration in ASG.
For example, if CPU utilization >70% scale up by adding additional ec2 instance ,and if the CPU utilization <30% ,reduce number of ec2 instance.
Here , I do not see elastic load balancer going up and down but only ec2 instance.
So AWS load balancer is called as elastic load balancer?

Answer (score 0):

> Will AWS loadbalancer scale up and down? How it happens?

The mechanics of AWS' Load balancers are a blackbox and they will scale up behind the scenes. AWS will scale up/down their load balancers using [LCUs](https://aws.amazon.com/elasticloadbalancing/pricing/#LCU_Details) as a metric.

Answer (score 0):

AWS does the Elastic Load Balancer scaling for you, behind the scene.

When you create a Load Balancer (LB), some limits are set by AWS. When you enable an AZ for your LB, AWS creates a LB node in that AZ. The IP address that the LB DNS name resolves to is the IP address of the LB node.

As your LB receives traffic, new nodes will be created, and eventually terminate the old ones. And you will see your DNS name resolving to different IP addresses.

When you reach the limits set (defaults at LB creation time) by AWS, you will need to open a ticket with AWS support to pre-warm your LB.

Please check AWS [documentation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticloadbalancing/latest/userguide/how-elastic-load-balancing-works.html) and [article](https://aws.amazon.com/articles/best-practices-in-evaluating-elastic-load-balancing).